# How to use JQuery first selector for specific selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JQuery and have a question about the first selector. I would like to select the first li element which is a child of a class. When I go only with li:first, everything is fine but I couldn't use it under another class.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code.

**JS**

```
var navList;

navList = $('.nav-list').children();// select
console.log(navList);

var first = $('li:first');//Working but selection is not specific
//var first = $('.nav-list.li:first');//returning empty array??
//var first = $('.nav-list.children(li.filter(":first"))');//??? blocking the rest??
//var first = $('.nav-list.children().li.filter(":first")');//???
//var first = $('.nav-list.children().li:first');//???

console.log(first);
console.log("ended");
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

This is the HTML document that you'll use jQuery to modify. To take the quiz, click over to app.js!

-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="header">
            <nav id="nav" class="navigator">
                <h1>Nav Header</h1>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a>Item #1</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#2">Item #2</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#3">Item #3</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#4">Item #4</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#5">Item #5</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#6">Item #6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="articles">
            <input id="input" value="Cool Articles" type="text">
            <h1>Cool Articles</h1>
            <ul class="article-list">
                <li class="article-item">
                    <header>Article #1</header>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sapiente officiis beatae, ut consequuntur. Quos minus neque eius, nemo sunt excepturi eveniet amet veritatis voluptatibus corporis ea, blanditiis porro ad!</p>
                    <h3>Sample Image Title here</h3>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Placeholder Image">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="bold">James</li>
                        <li>Lily</li>
                        <li>Harry</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Magnam ex autem doloremque, tempore mollitia atque aut delectus corporis rem similique voluptates omnis reiciendis vitae impedit exercitationem unde quaerat, doloribus voluptatibus molestias et veritatis sed optio repudiandae? Provident, voluptates.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="article-item featured">
                    <header>Article #2</header>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil animi ipsum, incidunt mollitia modi cum, eum ex doloremque rerum quod, maiores quisquam, enim quam unde cumque! Quam, doloremque. Voluptatum, maxime!</p>
                    <p>Numquam et quae, quasi. Reiciendis nemo mollitia eveniet alias, debitis facere atque excepturi et beatae laudantium commodi optio unde amet vitae libero quas cupiditate, nam porro minus. Quisquam, odit non.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="article-item">
                    <header>Article #3</header>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ratione, cum doloremque molestias labore amet at dicta reiciendis repudiandae fuga atque adipisci pariatur distinctio suscipit perferendis provident, facere ad aut.</p>
                    <p>Temporibus sapiente odio eveniet enim perferendis maxime, ratione, accusantium suscipit alias, soluta architecto culpa pariatur. Cupiditate nam eaque dolore voluptatem necessitatibus corporis iusto adipisci, dignissimos error, vitae quam, aliquid eius!</p>
                </li>
                <li class="article-item">
                    <header>Article #4</header>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate commodi, est soluta eos voluptates eum! Modi sit quia ipsum fugiat nesciunt, assumenda deleniti consequuntur molestias reprehenderit. Voluptate corporis illum nam?</p>
                    <p>Quia, omnis. Quasi necessitatibus, ducimus, deserunt ipsa, reprehenderit sit a dolore fuga placeat magni culpa ipsam quas id aut veniam rerum pariatur enim harum recusandae quo odio consequuntur. Maxime, aperiam.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:HTML code has been copied from Udacity JQuery course.

Comment: `.nav-list li:first` — the space between `.nav-list` and `li` mean that `li:first` must be a descendant of the matched `.nav-list` element.

Comment: `.nav-list.li:first` says to find elements that **both** classes `nav-list` and `li`, and get the first one.  It's just like a css selector.

Answer (score 3):

You should combine your selector with [Descendant Selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

`var first = $('.nav-list li:first');`

This means that you look for `li:first` inside of `.nav-list`.

More about jQuery selectors [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. So if I am using basic filter elements with ":" in front of them I should use notation >> $('.className.anotherClass element:basicFilter') or is this only the case for :first?

Comment: @user9629128 No, jQuery has css-like selectors. For more information look at: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Patryk Uszynski for the helpful information. I also find another way to do it.

Update:

:first is a basic filter element and there is regular filter selector in JQuery for exactly same task which is first(). So .nav-list.children().first() should just work fine.